# Proving the inequality $a^4+b^4+c^4+2abc(a+b+c)\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^4}9$

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers prove the following inequality $a^4+b^4+c^4+2abc(a+b+c)\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^4}9$.

Comment: Well, it's obviously true for $a,b,c\geq1$

Comment: You should show what you have already worked out...

Comment: @Ari why obvious?

Comment: @Macavity in the original problem the r.h.s. was $(a+b+c^4)/9$, for $a,b,c \geq 1$ the problem was indeed trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding, this is equivalent to (with $\sum$ denoting cyclic sums):
$$4\sum a^4  +3 abc\sum a \ge 2\sum ab(a^2+b^2)+3\sum a^2b^2 $$

which follows from combining Schur's inequality of fourth degree
$$3\sum a^4+3abc\sum a \ge 3\sum ab(a^2+b^2)$$
with the AM GMs:
$$\sum a^4 \ge \sum a^2b^2, \quad \sum ab(a^2+b^2) \ge 2\sum a^2b^2$$

Comment: You're welcome. Usually when you find terms like $abc$ on the higher side of the inequality, Schur is useful in using it up efficiently. AM-GM helps after such terms are rid.

Comment: What when it shows up on the lower side ?

Comment: On the lower side usually it is not a problem, as AM GM has that form.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously true for all $a,b,c$ real numbers.

Comment: You are right! uvw kills your inequality immediately.